Primes in the form $pk+n$
This statement appears to hold for small values of $n$ and $p$ (tested for $n < 100000$ and $p < 10000$):
For each positive integer $n$, and for any prime number $p > n$, there exists a positive integer $k < p$ such that $pk + n$ is prime.
This suggests some connection with Dirichlet’s theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, though the exact nature of that connection remains unclear to me.
Is there a way to derive this statement from any established theorem or conjecture?

"Appears" is a fairly weak word. How many pairs $n,p$ have you tried?

To restate the conjecture, for any prime $p$, there exist integers $a,b<p$ such that $p^2-(a-1)p-b \in \mathbb P$. By Bertrand's postulate, there should be a prime between $p^2/2$ and $p^2$ which should be describable by a suitable choice of $a,b$.

@KeithBackman That's not quite the same - the original conjecture is that it holds true for all choices of $n$, while your version only requires at least one value of $n$ which works.

@DietrichBurde The condition $k<p$ indicates a restraint on the smallest such prime.

@ThomasAndrews A quick computer search doesn't find any counterexamples with $p<10000$, though it's always possible I've got a bug.

Put it in your question. A person helping you might waste their time repeating your work.

Can you give me an example? What if $p = 5$, what is $k$?
is $k$ a constant? How does that make sense? If $pk$ + 1 is prime then $pk$ + 2 is not prime.

$k$ depends on $p$ and $n.$ @qatest

@Toph You are right; in my statement the formula must be correct for all $b<p$, which rules out reliance on Bertrand. Oops!

The statement is equivalent to the conjecture: The smallest prime that is congruent to $n$ modulo $p$ is always less than $p^2$. This is believed to be true but is an open problem. By the most current form of Linnik's theorem, the statement is known (for sufficiently large $p$) when $p^2$ is replaced by $p^5$. But we can't even prove the $p^2$ version if we assume the generalized Riemann hypothesis.
